# If $0\le x_1\le\dots\le x_n\le1$, then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(x_i-\frac{i}{n+1}\right)^2\le\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i}{n+1}\right)^2$

Tags: inequality, rearrangement-inequality

> Given positive integer $n$, $0\leq x_1 \leq \dots \leq x_n \leq 1$. Prove that $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i- \frac{i}{n+1} \right)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i}{n+1}\right) ^2
> $$

I try to use transformation $x_i=\sum_{k=1}^i y_k$, prove the case when n=2, with a few discussions. It seems hard for $n\geq 3$. Any help is appreciated. Thx.

Comment: @Michael: May I ask why you added the [rearrangement-inequality] tag? The question is not about the rearrangement inequality, does not mention it, and even the answer does not use it.

Comment: @Martin R The Cebysov's inequality it's just Rearrangement inequality. Click our tag  Rearrangement and read about it or read about it in Wikipedia.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: There are different proofs for the Chebyshev's sum inequality inequality. With such reasoning, you could tag all questions about AM-GM with  [rearrangement-inequality] as well, because that is a possible proof. – Also I am not sure if a tag should be added only because an *answer* makes use of a technique.

Comment: ... but apparently there are different opinions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/about-extending-the-tag-system-to-answers-too, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/retagging-after-an-answer-is-given.

Comment: @Martin R AM-GM inequality and Chebyshov with Rearrangement they are two different galaxies. The inequality proof in this topic was based on the rearrangement idea, which is the Cebyshov's inequality in our case. If you'll want (I hope that it's so!) to learn, how we can use Rearrangement or Chebyshov  inequality you'll can click in the tag Rearrangement and see how we can do it. Good luck!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: The first proof in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality is a straight-forward calculation and requires no rearrangement. That proof also generalizes to the continuous version.

Comment: @Martin R See please better the second proof. It's just rearrangement. Rearrangement and the Chebyshov's inequality these two things that always was together.

Comment: @Martin R The proof of Rigel (it's not full proof, but the  decisive hint) is very beautiful. User, which want to learn Rearrangement or Chebyshov, can click Rearrangement and to read this proof. Without tag Rearrangement this proof will lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
you can use the [Chebyshev sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) to prove that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \cdot \frac{i}{n+1}
\geq \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 
\frac{i}{n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i.
$$